# Playframework Hibernate JPA cannot connect to Database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I'm trying to configure Hibernate JPA to access database. Without using Hibernate JPA, It accesses to database well, but when using Hibernate JPA it does not.

I'm following this tutorial:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaJPA

These are my steps:

### build.sbt

```
//Hibernate JPA 
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(   javaJpa,   "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "5.1.0.Final" // replace by your jpa implementation ) 

//JPA 
PlayKeys.externalizeResources := false

//Driver for mysql 
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36"
```

### conf/application.conf

```
    db {
        # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
        # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

        default.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        default.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"
        default.username = root
        default.password = "root"

        default.jndiName=DefaultDS
        jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

        default.logSql=true
    }
```

### conf/META_INF/persistence.xml

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
         version="2.1">

      <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        </properties>
      </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

Error messages:

```
! @70fdppp3i - Internal server error, for (GET) [/count] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [jpa]]
        at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
        at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:806)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
        at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72)
        at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62)
        at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required]
        at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:154)
        at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:996)
        at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:70)
        at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:138)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: either dataSource or dataSourceClassName is required
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig.validate(HikariConfig.java:785)
        at play.api.db.HikariCPConfig.toHikariConfig(HikariCPModule.scala:141)
        at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:57)
        at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54)
        at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:123)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:121)
        at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:142)
```

Error message on screen:

[image]

How to solve it?

I'm using Play framework 2.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your jpa.default property is in wrong place. Try like this:

```
db {
    # You can declare as many datasources as you want.
    # By convention, the default datasource is named `default`

    default.driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    default.url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sakila"
    default.username = root
    default.password = "root"

    default.jndiName=DefaultDS

    default.logSql=true
}

jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Gus, You're right. It works for me.